# Create navigation headings in SharePoint Online programatically

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, navigation, .net

Is there a possibility to create headings with multiple links in the navigation bar (i.e. top link bar) in SharePoint online using c3 or PowerShell?
My initial guess was to use `ClientContext` to gain access in the following way.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
// Get the Quick Launch navigation node collection.
NavigationNodeCollection collQuickLaunchNode = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
// Get the top navigatin node collection
NavigationNodeCollection collTopNavigationNode = web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar;
```

so here I can add a link using

```
NavigationNodeCreationInformation ciNavigationNode = new NavigationNodeCreationInformation();
ciNavigationNode.Title = "Title";
ciNavigationNode.Link = "www.Link.com";
collTopNavigationNode.Add(ciNavigationNode);
clientContext.Load(collTopNavigationNode);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

But what I want is actually a heading that contains links. The links that go in the headings are external links and links of other site collections.

Is there a possibility to to this? If so how?

I have the feature (SharePoint Server Publishing) to modify the navigation turned on and am using an Office 365 tenant with SharePoint Online.

Comment: Have you tried not setting the `Link` property of the `NavigationNodeCreationInformation`?  Set the `IsExternal` property to true for the links.  As to how to get them under the header, I do not know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried not setting a link and it shows the node, but the problem is still how to get links under the header ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying to do the same

In SSOM this is possible with

`$librariesNode.Properties["BlankUrl"] = "True"`

unfortunately, from what I have found it is NOT possible in CSOM

however this guy did it by adding

`javascript: return true;`

to the url field.

[Quick Launch: add new heading without an URL](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43fcf510-03e6-409c-85ac-84347eccb865/quick-launch-add-new-heading-without-an-url?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

As for adding a hierarchy, here's the code (using the newly created heading node to add child nodes):

```
#heading
$libraries = new-object
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation
$libraries.Title = "Libraries"
$librariesNode = $ql.Add($libraries)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

#link inside heading
$library = new-object
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation
$library.Title = $title
$library.Url = $url.ServerRelativeUrl
$library.AsLastNode = $true
$librariesNode.Children.Add($library) | Out-Null            
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the *NavigationNode* object that is returned by

`var headerNode = collTopNavigationNode.Add(ciNavigationNode);`

method call. On the returned object, add the nodes you want to have as child links via

```
headerNode.Children.Add(new NavigationNodeCreationInformation { Title = "Child Link", ... });
headerNode.Update();
```

Will let you have the desired result

Answer (score 0):

**CSOM PowerShell code:**

To create list heading without URL, try below code. It is tested for SharePoint Online.

```
$newNavNode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation;
$newNavNode.Title = "Office 365";
$newNavNode.AsLastNode = $true;
$newNavNode.IsExternal = $true;

$libheading = $dQLaunchColl.Add($newNavNode);
```

Property "IsExternal = $true" does all magic here. Once it is set to true, ExecuteQuery() will not validate URL.